# Error when installing 32-bit Windows 7 in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, 32-bit

I tried installing a 64-bit Windows 7 in VirtualBox, but apparently my 64-bit laptop will not allow that. So I tried installing 32-bit Windows 7, but I get this error:

```
Failed to open the optical disk file C:\Users\Major Lee\Downloads\X17-24208.iso.

Could not get the storage format of the medium 'C:\Users\Major Lee\Downloads\X17-24208.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong. I tried re-downloading the iso too. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can it open other ISOs or just this one? If you've redownloaded the ISO I suspect its an issue with Virtalbox.

Comment: I tried xp and I get an error too. Should I re download VB?

Comment: yeah, do a complete uninstall / reinstall. something's not right.

Comment: before you do that, try creating a new VM

Comment: I have several times. I tried uninstalling from control panel and re-installing but all my old VM I tried to get work were still there and I tried making a new one again but still nothing.

Comment: Likely, the downloaded ISOs are faulty. Have you checked their MD5 sums against those published with the images?

Comment: I am not sure whats going on here. Question title says 32 bit and the body says 64 bit windows. And AFAIK, Virtualbox needs to be running on 64-bit host OS if you want to install 64-bit guest OS.

Comment: @tumchaaditya I meant I can't do 64 bit so I am trying 32 bit. My OS is 64 by the way.

Comment: I downloaded them here http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Have you tried the ISOs in VMWare Player by any chance?

Comment: @Darius Tried it and it says I need to boot it with a flash drive but it won't find my flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VT-x is turned on in the BIOS.